# checking array point with high score

Tags: php

my intention is to check a array , i will be setting one of the point as high score , and if in the array any other 3 is same score as the high score , echo there is 2 same point else echo not the same. so basically is checking all point any having same point.

my code

```
$Dpoint =70;
$Ipoint =70;
$Hpoint =60;
$Apoint =60;

$score = $Dpoint; high score

$xdata = array(
            'D1' => $Dpoint,
            'I1' => $Ipoint,
            'H1' => $Hpoint,
            'A1' => $Apoint
            );

    foreach($xdata as $key => $value){
    if($score == $value){
    echo "there is 2 same point";
    }else{
    echo "not the same";
    }
}
```

but i am getting werid result , what part i missed ? fix me

Comment: *werid result* What do you mean with that? Please show the output which you get and what you would expect, also works fine for me (BTW: You forgot to close your foreach loop)

Comment: Define "weird results", this code checks every element of $xdata array against $score variable...

Comment: sorry i mislead you guys , please read again i edit the post , thank for reading for my bad English , i hope i get you guys understand.

Comment: Apparently code is working fine. What is your output and an expected output too?

Comment: @babayaga I still don't get it! Please add your **current** output and your **expected** output!

Comment: so Dpoint is the high score right ? i wanted to check other 3 array is any same as the high score except Dpoint. all i want when there is same array as high score (except it self) echo false.

Comment: $Dpoint is same with $Ipoint but it echo not the same

Comment: there is 2 same pointnot the samenot the samenot the same

Comment: @babayaga Your code works: https://eval.in/307459 ?! ^ Please read my last comment!

Comment: can i skip the $Dpoint check it self? i only want it to echo "not the same"

Comment: thank you rizier123 , i am so dumb fixed becasue i for got the $score = $Dpoint;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well...

```
<?php
    $Dpoint =70;
    $Ipoint =70;
    $Hpoint =60;
    $Apoint =60;

    $score = $Dpoint;

    $xdata = array(
                   'D1' => $Dpoint,
                   'I1' => $Ipoint,
                   'H1' => $Hpoint,
                   'A1' => $Apoint
                   );

    $matches = 0;
    foreach($xdata as $key => $value){
        if($score == $value){
            $matches ++;
        }
    }

    echo $matches > 0 ? "$matches same point(s)": "no same points";
?>
```

Comment: thank you fixed ~ asking dumb question i forgot the $score = $Dpoint

Comment: got it sorry i remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389865/checking-array-point-with-high-score#comment46957657_29389865):

> can i skip the $Dpoint check it self? i only want it to echo "not the same" –  babayaga 5 mins ago

If you don't want the high score to be in your loop just [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) it and the key you can get with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
unset($xdata[array_search($score, $xdata)]);
```